# What does this code mean get_option( 'woocommerce_db_version', null )?

Tags: php, wordpress

if ( version_compare( get_option( 'woocommerce_db_version', null ), '3.6', '<' ) ) {
return;
}

I want to know the detail description that what is the meaning of version_compare , get_option , 'woocommerce_db_version', null  etc . Please describe them. I want to learn

Comment: Use the Wordpress code reference to explore Wordpress functions https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/ and use https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/ to explore functions that belong to WooCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn and use wordpress just go to  where all the developer documentation is: https://developer.wordpress.org/.
There you can find description for all the functions (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/), for us interesting is: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/

```
get_option( string $option, mixed $default = false )

Retrieves an option value based on an option name.
```

There is also description and parameters documentation:

```
$option (string) (Required) Name of option to retrieve. Expected to not be SQL-escaped.
$default (mixed) (Optional) Default value to return if the option does not exist.
Default value: false
```

So `get_option` retrieves option from db by the name (`woocommerce_db_version`) that was previously stored or returns `null` (second parameter) if it was not previously set.

Now version_compare - this is php function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php

```
version_compare — Compares two "PHP-standardized" version number strings
```

Here 3 parameter version is used:

```
version_compare ( string $version1 , string $version2 , string $operator ) : bool
```

So in the code you provided we ask if version stored in options of `woocommerce_db_version` is lower `<` than `3.6`. If it is we return (do nothing more) but if it not lower we execute code below.

Use IDE for your code and all this documentation will be under your fingertips either by hovering over functions or by clicking on them.

Use php -a interactive shell to just test some code/functions, for example:

```
php > var_dump( version_compare(null, '3.8', '<'));
bool(true)
php > var_dump( version_compare('3.7', '3.8', '<'));
bool(true)
php > var_dump( version_compare('3.8', '3.8', '<'));
bool(false)
php > var_dump( version_compare('3.9', '3.8', '<'));
bool(false)
```

And if you want to know what 'woocommerce_db_version' option exactly is go to woocommerce github page and search for it https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?q=%27woocommerce_db_version%27&unscoped_q=%27woocommerce_db_version%27 as all of this is open source code.